# Average Value of Area Closed by Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Two dimensional brownian motion will intersect its own path infinitly many times. What is the average value of area, closed by curve during an intersection in brownian motion?

[image]

Comment: In what sense do you mean area? If you count the area with multiplicities, the expectation does not exist. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/130532/area-of-a-brownian-bridge-on-the-plane. Do you count areas where the winding number is 0, but there is no path to infinity disjoint from the Brownian path?

Comment: What is the meaning of "Area With Multiplicity" in your comment?

Comment: The topological multiplicity is the winding number of the curve around the point. If you take something like $(cost(t),sin(t))$ for $t\in[0,4\pi]$, this winds around the origin twice. If you take a figure-8 knot, $4_1$, or the knots $6_1$ or $7_2$, with their standard minimum crossing diagrams, there is a bounded region about which the knot has $0$ winding number. Would you want to count that area as $0$ or $1$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to define the "enclosed area" for a curve $\mathbf{r}(t)$ in the $x$-$y$ plane of duration $T$, with $\mathbf{r}(0)=\mathbf{r}(T)$, is via the socalled algebraic area $A=\tfrac{1}{2}\int_0^T (\mathbf{r}\times\dot{\mathbf{r}})\cdot\hat{z}\,dt$. (The dot indicates the time derivative and $\hat{z}$ is a unit vector perpendicular to the plane.) A loop traversed in counterclockwise direction contributes a positive amount to $A$, clockwise propagation contributes a negative amount. The probability distribution of $A$ for Brownian motion is known [1,2,3,4],

$$P(A)=\frac{\pi}{4DT}\cosh^{-2}\left(\frac{\pi A}{2DT}\right).$$

The two-dimensional diffusion constant is defined by the mean square displacement,

$$E(|\mathbf{r}(T)-\mathbf{r}(0)|^2)=4DT.$$

The average of $A$ itself is zero (because positive and negative contributions cancel), the average of $|A|$ is

$$E(|A|)= \frac{2DT\log 2}{\pi}.$$

[1] P. Lévy,  [Le mouvement Brownien plan](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2371467?sid=21105951236391&uid=3738736&uid=4&uid=2) (1940), and later references [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123683900538).

[2] D.C. Khandekar and F.W. Wiegel, [Distribution of the area enclosed by a plane random walk](http://iopscience.iop.org/0305-4470/21/10/006) (1988).

[3] B. Duplantier, [Areas of planar Brownian curves](http://www.iecn.u-nancy.fr/~krikun/pub/duplantier/duplantier-1989-areas-planar-brownian-curves.pdf)
 (1989).

[4] A. Comtet, J. Desbois, and S. Ouvry, [Winding of planar Brownian curves](http://www.iaea.org/inis/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/22/017/22017201.pdf) (1990).

Comment: This is a bit subtle for Brownian motion because the time derivative doesn't exist.  Basically, the nowhere-differentiability of Brownian motion prevents you from sensibly determining whether a loop is being traversed clockwise or counterclockwise, since you don't know which direction it's going at any given moment.  The usual solution is to replace the Riemann integral with a stochastic integral, giving you what's known as the Levy area process.  I don't have access to the paper you link right now, so I'm not certain if their model is equivalent.

Comment: thanks for the caveat, I added pertinent references to Lévy and later work.

Answer (score 6):

There is a beautiful connection between the area swept out by Brownian motion and the Dirichlet function:

$L(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^s}$.

> **Proposition**: Let $A_t$ be the area swept out by the Brownian motion up to time $t$. Then for every $\alpha \ge 0$
>   $$\mathbb{E}(|A_t|^\alpha)=\frac{4 \Gamma(1+\alpha)}{\pi^{1+\alpha}} L(1+\alpha)t^\alpha$$

**Proof:** Let $B_t=(B^1_t,B^2_t)$ be a two-dimensional Brownian motion. The algebraic area enclosed by $B$ up to time $t$ is given by

$A_t=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^t B_s^1 dB_s^2-B_s^2dB_s^1$

where the integral is understood as a Ito integral. It is an easy exercise to check that

$A_t=\frac{1}{2} \beta_{\int_0^t \rho_s^2 ds}$

where $\rho_t=\| B_t \|$ and $\beta$ is a Brownian motion independent from $\rho$.

Thus we have,

$\mathbb{E}(| A_t |^\alpha)=\frac{1}{2^\alpha} \mathbb{E}\left(\left| \beta_{\int_0^t \rho_s^2 ds} \right|^\alpha \right)$

Using the Brownian scaling property and the independence, we obtain

$\mathbb{E}(| A_t |^\alpha)=\frac{1}{2^\alpha} \mathbb{E}\left(| \beta_{1} |^\alpha\right) \mathbb{E}\left(\left( \int_0^t \rho_s^2 ds\right)^{\alpha/2}\right)=\frac{t^\alpha}{2^\alpha} \mathbb{E}\left(| \beta_{1} |^\alpha\right) \mathbb{E}\left(\left( \int_0^1 \rho_s^2 ds\right)^{\alpha/2}\right)$

Now, [it is well-known](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1990.2/Main/icm1990.2.1105.1112.ocr.pdf) that for every $\lambda \ge 0$

$\mathbb{E}\left(e^{-\frac{\lambda^2}{2} \int_0^1 \rho_s^2 ds}\right)=\frac{1}{\cosh \lambda} .$

We can deduce from this Laplace transform the following Mellin transform formula

$\mathbb{E}\left(\left( \int_0^1 \rho_u^2 du\right)^{s}\right)=\Gamma(1+s)2^{1+s} \left(\frac{2}{\pi} \right)^{2s+1}L(1+2s)$

The result follows then easily.

Comment: hmm, I'm a bit confused: the average of $|A|$ would give $L(2)$ which is the Catalan number, which seems to disagree with the answer I found in the literature.

Comment: The formula you give is for the Brownian loop, not for the Brownian motion. The Brownian loop is the Brownian motion conditioned to go back at 0 at time T. Unfortunately, the Fourier transform of the area swept out by the Brownian motion can not be inverted simply and the distribution of A is not known. I found the above formula for the Brownian motion quite cute and it was too long for a comment, so I put it as an answer.

Comment: thanks for the clarification; if the path is not closed, wouldn't the definition of "enclosed area" depend on the choice of origin? (I'm thinking of a straight line, what area does it "enclose"?)

Comment: Yes indeed, it depends on the starting point. The computation I do is for the Brownian motion B started at 0 and run up to time t. I then look at the algebraic area between the segment [0,B_t] and the curve up to time t. So the formula is  $A_t=1/2 \int_0^t B_s \times dB_s$ where the integral is understood as a Ito integral.

Comment: @Fabrice:I am sorry about the naivety of the question but is obvious that $\mathbb{E}(|A_t|)$ is non--zero just from its definition as an area ?

Comment: @Captain Darling, since $|A_t|$ is non negative, $\mathbb{E}(|A_t|)=0$ would imply $A_t=0$ almost surely, which is not possible.

Comment: This gives a new proof that there are infinitely may primes which are $1\mod{4}$ and also $3\mod{4}$ because there are easy arguments in number theory that show that $L(1)\neq 0$ is automatically equivalent to the existence of infinitely many primes. Could you prove a similar identity involving the function $L(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{=\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(3n+1)^s}+\frac{-1}{(3n+1)^s}\right)$? This would show that there are infinitely many primes $p\equiv 1 \mod{3}$.